# Is there a way not to consume data from socket?

Tags: sockets, networking

I am developing very simple web server. but I need to check out what request type. static or dynamic. So before handling request, I must check it out for scheduling. Is there any socket option for this ?

To sum up, I need a way not to consume data from socket. I looked for this stuff about socket option to achieve my goal. But I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [recv(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv) documentation:

> flags
>
> Specifies the type of message reception. Values of this argument
>   are formed by logically OR'ing zero or more of the following values:
>
> MSG_PEEK Peeks at an incoming message. The data is treated as unread
>   and the next recv() or similar function shall still return this data.

In other words, specify MSG_PEEK as the last parameter to recv() and you can read data from the socket while leaving it in the buffer.